# Spark Structed Streaming read nested json from kafka and flatten it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

A json type data :

```json
{
    "id": "34cx34fs987",
    "time_series": [
        {
            "time": "2020090300: 00: 00",
            "value": 342342.12
        },
        {
            "time": "2020090300: 00: 05",
            "value": 342421.88
        },
        {
            "time": "2020090300: 00: 10",
            "value": 351232.92
        }
    ]
}
```

I got the json from kafka:

```scala
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")...
```

How can I manipulate df to get a DataFrame as shown below:

```
     id             time          value
34cx34fs987  20200903 00:00:00  342342.12
34cx34fs987  20200903 00:00:05  342421.88
34cx34fs987  20200903 00:00:10  351232.92
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using Scala:

If you define your schema as

```scala
val schema: StructType = new StructType()
    .add("id", StringType)
    .add("time_series", ArrayType(new StructType()
      .add("time", StringType)
      .add("value", DoubleType)
    ))
```

you can then make use of Spark SQL built-in functions `from_json` and `explode`

```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import spark.implicits._

  val df1 = df
    .selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as json")
    .select(from_json('json, schema).as("data"))
    .select(col("data.id").as("id"), explode(col("data.time_series")).as("time_series"))
    .select(col("id"), col("time_series.time").as("time"), col("time_series.value").as("value"))
```

Your output will be then

```sh
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|id         |time             |value    |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|34cx34fs987|20200903 00:00:00|342342.12|
|34cx34fs987|20200903 00:00:05|342421.88|
|34cx34fs987|20200903 00:00:10|351232.92|
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code in pyspark

```
df2 = df.select("id", f.explode("time_series").alias("col"))
df2.select("id", "col.time", "col.value").show()
```